# PHP variable is not working with WHERE clause

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

My query is not working when I use the variable in the WHERE clause. I have tried everything. I echo the variable $res, it shows me the perfect value, when I use the variable in the query the query is not fetching anything thus mysqli_num_rows is giving me the zero value, but when I give the value that the variable contains statically the query executes perfectly. I have used the same kind of code many times and it worked perfectly, but now in this part of module it is not working.

Code:

```php
$res = $_GET['res']; // I have tried both post and get
echo $res; //here it echos the value = mahanta
$query = "SELECT * FROM `seller` WHERE `restaurant` = '$res'"; // Here it contains the problem I have tried everything. Note: restaurant name is same as it is in the database $res contains a value and also when I give the value of $res i.e. mahanta in the query it is then working.
$z = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($z);
echo var_dump($row2); // It is giving me null
$num = mysqli_num_rows($z); // Gives zero

if ($num > 0) {
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($z)) {
        $no = $row2['orders'];
        $id = $res . $no;
    }
}
else {
    echo "none selected";
}
```

Comment: instead of '$res' use '".$res."'

Comment: You should take the habit not to inject directly variables into SQL strings and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Also, `echo var_dump()` is not really correct, you should either use `echo` or `var_dump` but not together like this. `var_dump` returns nothing so no need to echo it

Comment: Is `$conn` defined? Nothing in your logs? Nothing in `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: $query ="SELECT * FROM `seller` WHERE `restaurant` = " . $res;
only you are getting $res as string in your query as it's quotes are not organized to the query structure.

Comment: You say you've used both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.. But which one do you send the data over? These are things you need to know before you can build your application - how do you receive the data.

Comment: 1) @Ravishankar ... i have already used both  used both of them , it didn't worked out .

Comment: @kadath issue is something different  ! the error is not because of these things !!

Comment: @kerbolz yes man it is defined ! how is it working statically i think u have not read my question fully !

Comment: @joel it doesn't work !

Comment: @noman it is a string therefore i have to use it in ' '

Comment: @qirel when i used get i have send data by get method n vise versa

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM seller WHERE restaurant  ='".$res."'";

Comment: @uzairrashid `$res` is a variable that contains string value. So you are using the variable name in your query not the string that is `mahanta`. So please correct your syntax. You may view your query by using `var_dump($query)` not by `var_dump($row2)` . Hope it will help you a lot.

Comment: @NomanJavid yes noman ! tell me how will i use the value of $res in the query ? where am i wrong in my syntax ! as i have told u i have used the same way many times it is working there but not here in this part of code please help

Comment: @nomanJavid i used the var_dump($query) and it showed a lil space in $res value it as like ... restaurant = ' mahanta' that lil space before mahanta was creating all the problem !! now i got it where was the actual problem . thanku 

Comment: @uzairrashid great.!  if you need an answer I can format that for your question. So the other users may get help in future.

Comment: yes please @nomanjaved. var_dump($query) was the key solution to my problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment. By printing the query `var_dump($query)`, you will get the exact syntax that you are sending to your database to query.

**Debugging Tip**: You can also test by pasting the var_dump($query) value in your database and you will see the results if your query is okay.

So update your query syntax and print the query will help you.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `seller` WHERE `restaurant` = '$res'";
var_dump($query);
```

Hope this will help you and for newbies in future, how to test your queries.

**Suggestion**: Also see how to write a mysql query syntax for better understanding [php variables inside mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: my pleasure @uzairrashid

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the way you're using `$res` in your query. Use `.$res` instead. In PHP (native or framework), injecting variables into queries need a proper syntax.

Comment: `mysql_*` are deprecated, don't use them

Comment: @kerbholz alrighty, didn't know that, I rarely use native PHP.

Comment: It says it right there on that page: "_Warning This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 ..._" ;)

Comment: "*It's cleaner to read*" is a very individual thing though. I prefer OOP over procedural, for example. `mysql_` shouldn't be used whatever your preference is though.

Comment: @Qirel True, going to simply delete this.

Comment: i used the sprintf as u have suggested but still is not working ! I don't know y ! this is a serious bug ! please help

Comment: What? His syntax is correct, the value should be inserted properly.